# Find youtube links on other pages

Tags: hyperlink, youtube

I want to create a php page, that finds things on other sites.
Well, lets give an example to make you understand. Lets say there is a website called "anwebsite.com" and it have an page called "anwebsite.com/page.php" 
I want to create a php script that find in that link if there are any youtube links (from embed for example) in his source, and get it.

Example:

$thesitelink = ("http://anwebsite.com/page.php") ( Lets say I put the link mannualy in the php page)
Then, here should be some scrips to find if on that page are any youtube links. If there is at least on, it doesn't matter if there are many, its enought at least one then put the link in a varialbe like $theyoutubelink. Like this:

$theyoutubelink = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx

So the input data is $thesitelink and the output should be an youtube link (if there is one on that page)

Comment: Can you please post the important pieces of your code here? Links can change in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a spider/crawler + parser.
First things first:
- Use CURL to get all the source html from the website crawled.
- Use Regular Expressions to parse Youtube links (don't forget short url ones)
Do you have any code made already?

Comment: Well, I was waiting for an response like yours. Now I'll try to make the script and I'll post it here. :)

Comment: Ok, consider this lib: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/ will make your job easier. Or this simple crawler: http://webdevwonders.com/simple-php-crawler-example/

Comment: This one is very nice, you just have to rule out all other url different from youtube: http://subinsb.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-crawler-in-php